# How to acess javascript-based dialog window in web page with Windows Powershell?

Tags: html, powershell, web, automation, automated-tests

I'm accessing an old web page, poorly scripted, with poorly identified elements. Until now, I could access all objects it gave me. But now, I'm stucked.

When I click this button, it opens a JavaScript dialog, in which the user must insert some values. And I just click at it. But when the window opens, I just can't focus at it.

This is the code that creates it:

```bsh
<INPUT onclick="javascript: openCosts(document.forms[0], 'COMPANY');" 
title="Include values" 
style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 1px; CURSOR: hand; FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 1px; 
BORDER-TOP-COLOR: #007041; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 1px; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: #007041; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; 
COLOR: #fff; PADDING-BOTTOM: 1px; BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: #007041; PADDING-TOP: 1px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; 
BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: #007041; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 1px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #0080ff" 
type=button value="Costs - SAP" name=btn_show_costs></INPUT>
```

I tried to send TABS and ENTERS; tried to get all open IExplorer open windows -- $shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application and Get-Process | Where-Object ... doesn't work.

Can somebody help me??

That's the resumed code, until now...

```
$ie= new-object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.Navigate("an_local_asp_web_page.asp")

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}

$ie.Document.getElementById("frame_principal").contentDocument.getElementById("cbb_profile")[2].selected = $true
$ie.Document.getElementById("frame_principal").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[1].click()

start-sleep -m 2000

$image = $ie.Document.getElementById("frame_principal").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("IMG") | Where-Object { $_.href -like "*img_menu.gif*" }
$image.click() 

start-sleep -m 2000

$ie.Document.getElementById("frame_principal").contentDocument.getElementById("menu_vehicle").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[0].click()

start-sleep -m 1000

$ie.Document.getElementById("frame_principal").contentDocument.getElementById("frame_body").contentDocument.getElementsByName(“txt_user”)[0].value = "NICHOLAS"
$ie.Document.getElementById("frame_principal").contentDocument.getElementById("frame_body").contentDocument.getElementsByName(“rd_driver”)[0].Click()
$ie.Document.getElementById("frame_principal").contentDocument.getElementById("frame_body").contentDocument.getElementsByName(“btn_show_costs”)[0].Click() 

start-sleep -m 1000

# Now, that next part should work... But it doen't. It says 
# 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.'
# I only see the IE Window that generates the Dialog Window... 
$app = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$app.Windows()
$window = $app.Windows() | where {$_.LocationName -like "*show costs*"} 
$image = $window.Document.getElementsByTagName("IMG") | Where-Object { $_.href -like "*bt_add_cost.gif*" }
$image.click()

start-sleep -m 1000

$window.Document.getElementById("rate_cd_cbi").Value = "COSTCENTER"
$window.Document.getElementById("rate").Value = "100"
$window.Document.getElementById("btn_include").Click()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Provide more information regarding your problem. openCosts function can be provided as well as any console errors if any

Comment: Hi! Thank you! When we click the button, it shots this request "http://<mumblejamblegage>.asp?acao=&cbi=@&cac=@&tipo=@&rateio=@&v_programmed_items=". It helps? I coud not find the function that generates the dialog window...